# Do Meteor-Roles and Iron-Router play nicely together?

Tags: meteor, roles, iron-router

I have a Meteor app with an editor page that should only be accessible to editors. I am using Iron-Router and my Router.map looks like the following. However, this is not working in an odd way. If I provide a link to the editor page, then all is well, but if I try entering the /editor url, then it always redirects to home, even if the user role is correctly set.

(One thing I ruled out was if Meteor.userId() is not set before Roles.userIsInRole is called in before.)

Anyone know why this would be?

```
Router.map(function() {
      ...
      this.route('editor', {
        path: '/editor',
        waitOn: function() {
          //handle subscriptions
        },
        data: function() {
          //handle data
        },
        before: function() {
          if ( !Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'editor') ) {
            this.redirect('home');
          }
        }
      });
      ...
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Roles` package sets up an [automatic publication](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) that sends the `roles` property on the `Meteor.users` collection. Unfortunately, you can't get a subscription handle for automatic publications, so you'll need to make your own.

Set up a new subscription that publishes the required data of a user, then configure Router to check that the data is ready before showing any page.

eg:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("user", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      fields: {
        roles: true
      }
    });
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var userData = Meteor.subscribe("user");
  Router.before(function() {
    if (Meteor.userId() == null) {
      this.redirect('login');
      return;
    }
    if (!userData.ready()) {
      this.render('logingInLoading');
      this.stop();
      return;
    }
    this.next(); // Needed for iron:router v1+
  }, {
    // be sure to exclude the pages where you don't want this check!
    except: ['register', 'login', 'reset-password']
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. What's Remodal?

Comment: Whoops, I've removed that. `Remodal` is a custom reactive modal package.